# Is it possible to use an LSTM for time series classification?

Tags: regression, time-series, classification, lstm

I've read a lot of literature on using LSTM's for time-series prediction in the regression sense; using past values to predict the next value in a time series.[[1]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925231218311639)[[2]](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/)

However, I have not come across any literature outlining if it is possible to use an LSTM to make a binary classification on a time series to predict something about the next value. For example, predicting whether the difference between the next value and current value will be above or below some threshold.

Are there any potential issues in using an LSTM to make binary predictions on a time series? Is it "correct" to do so or is there something mathematically incorrect in this setup?

Comment: Sure, you just hit it with an activation function like sigmoid at the end the way that you would do a link function in a generalized linear model to go to logistic regression.

Comment: If you can use them in a generative adversarial model like an MLP on steroids, then you can use them in time-series classification.  An output transformation might be required.

Comment: There's some literature on using deep learning for time series classification (for a review see https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.04356) and we've implemented many of the standard architectures in a Python toolbox: https://github.com/sktime/sktime-dl/tree/dev.